# Bufferedimage bitmask operations - apply a color to an image using another image as a mask

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have two BufferedImage objects, `src` and `dest`.  Both are grayscale, `src` is 1bpc (B&W basically), and `dest` could really be any sort of color space/bpc/etc.

I need to be able to draw some color onto `dest` using `src` as a bitmask.  Basically, if the pixel in `src` is black, then dest should be changed to the draw color.  But if the pixel in `src` is white, the `dest` should be left alone.

If it matters, I am also applying an affine transform during the draw operation.

```
Graphics2D g = dest.createGraphics();
// do something here???
g.drawImage(src, transform, null);
g.dispose();
```

In a pure B&W world this would involve a simple `|` of the pixel values together - but it seems like there's probably a correct way to do this using image operations.

Gut instinct says that this is a matter of setting the Composite and some sort of alpha - but I'm at a total loss as to what values to use.  I have very little experience with the more advanced aspects of graphics 2d - any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've come up with an effective solution using [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369809/how-to-replace-colors-in-bufferedimage-in-java)

This is certainly efficient, although I'm not sure if follows best practices or not:

```
BufferedImage dest; // input
BufferedImage src; // input

...

byte[] r = new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)255}; // 255=black, we could set it to some other gray component as desired
byte[] g = new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)255};
byte[] b = new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)255};
byte[] a = new byte[]{(byte)255,(byte)0};
IndexColorModel bitmaskColorModel = new IndexColorModel(1, 2, r, g, b, a);

BufferedImage masked = new BufferedImage(bitmaskColorModel, src.getRaster(), false, null);

Graphics2D g = dest.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(masked, transform, null);
g.dispose();
```