# How to remove all color except a certain rgb value

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb

Okay I need to get the program to scan the screen for a certain rgb value then change it to bright pink. I made the program and so far it scans the screen for a certain color. I do not know how to get it to change the pixel color. I think I need to upload a picture instead of having it scan the screen. But if I do that I still wouldn't know how to change the pixels.

Here's my code so far.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;


public class FindRgbOnScreen extends Thread{

    public Rectangle captureSize;

    public FindRgbOnScreen() {
        captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            while(true){
                BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
                WritableRaster r = img.getRaster();
                DataBuffer db = r.getDataBuffer();
                DataBufferInt dbi = (DataBufferInt)db;
                int[] data = dbi.getData();                 

                for (int x_scale = 0; x_scale < captureSize.width; x_scale += 1) {  //this scans the screen 
                    for(int y_scale = 0; y_scale < captureSize.height; y_scale += 1) {
                        int rgb = data[x_scale + captureSize.width * y_scale];
                        if (rgb == -5381164){
                            //change pixel to pink
                        }
                        else{
                            //change pixel to grey
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FindRgbOnScreen().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just iterate over the image and change all rgb that you want to magenta?

Comment: You should attempt to solve the problem yourself, then come back if you have specific questions. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: i didn't know if there was a picture editor out there that already could do this.

Comment: Added code. Any help would be great!

Comment: OK, what does your code currently do? What does it not do? What errors are you seeing? etc...

Comment: And is it your code? If not, where is it from? Do you understand it?

Comment: I started with a little of someone else's code then added more myself but I completely understand it. It currently scans the screen for a color and once it finds that color I can make it do something (ex. move the mouse to that color). There are no errors I just don't know how to do what I want to get done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these posts. You should use `ColorModel` which is the fastest way to do pixel color replacement instead of iterating over pixels:

- http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/changing-the-colormodel-of-a-bufferedimage
- [JAVA: Substitute one color with another using ColorModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882174/java-substitute-one-color-with-another-using-colormodel)
- [How to replace colors in BufferedImage in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369809/how-to-replace-colors-in-bufferedimage-in-java)