# Changing color of a moving image without lowering the fps

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage, frame-rate

I just added an option to my game that makes it so that all the enemies will have a random color for their clothes instead of the regular blue. I use this code to draw rectangles over the shirt of the enemy.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(z.getWidth(), z.getHeight(), 
    BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
try{
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ZombieGame\\
        Zombie.png"));
}catch (IOException ex) {
}
int j, k, red, green, blue;
    for(j = 0; j < z.getWidth(); j++){
        for(k = 0; k < z.getHeight(); k++){
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, k));
            red = c.getRed();
            green = c.getGreen();
            blue = c.getBlue();
            if(red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 178){
                g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(j,k, 1, 1);
                Path2D.Double rect = new Path2D.Double(r, at);
                g2d.fill(rect);
            }
        }
    }
```

The thing is that when I apply this the game will run twice as slow (before I added this code I got a solid 80 fps but as fast as I added it I got around 30 fps). My question is if there is a better way to do this in which I could change the color of specific parts of the image without lowering the fps drastically?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you shouldn't simply iterate over every pixel. As I can see, this will have 2 disadvantages:

1. If you have some pixels, that you don't want to change within same image;
2. It's really slow.

As for first argument, lets assume this wouldn't happen, as long as your image (apparently) contains single item.

And as for the second question, which is in fact is the main your question - I can suggest you looking applied answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369809/how-to-replace-colors-in-bufferedimage-in-java) and comments into it. It contains description on how to achieve your task faster, than iterating, and comment has a link to example - [here it is](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/changing-the-colormodel-of-a-bufferedimage)

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the orginal Image, change the pixels you want to change (any method that suits your fancy, be it drawing rectangles or replacing color values with getRGB/setRRG). Remember the altered image and reuse it for all subsequent renderings of the same color.

This way you pay the cost of changing the color pnly once, not every time you need to draw the image. If you don't have an excessive number of images, you may want to load them all before even starting the game. If there are too many images to load them all, some kind of LRU cache can be used to keep the most frequently used ones in memory.